# Optimizing large device array with insufficient device buffer space

Tags: memory-management, cuda, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've been working with a massive device array. After a certain limit, I discovered that the dynamical array inside the device (kernel: `dmemd`) suffers from an insufficient device buffer space problem (using nvprof around `g_size` = 8).

I attempted to define them from the host side (kernel: `dmemh`), and I have been able to create larger device arrays, but again, after a certain limit (using nvprof around `g_size` = 55k), the insufficient device buffer space problem returns. However, I need to go up to `g_size` = 120k.

About the algorithm:

1. I need to sum over `g_size` = 120k.
2. Inside the `g_size` loop, need to compute the a large `det` array.
3. Then sum for specific indices.
4. The example code below is a simplified version of the original sum.

About the attempted code architecture:

1. I had a g_size loop in the serial code, which I am putting on the GPU as g_size blocks (because the maximum CUDA blocks are 2^31).
2. At each block, create a `det` array based on the `blockIdx`, and then sum some specific indices in the `det` array.
3. Finally, compute the total sum, which is the sum of all blocks.

Other efficient parallelization schemes are also greatly appreciated.
Any suggestion on how to incorporate the threads into the above architecture? Right now I am just using thread blocks with 1 thread each

Here is the sample code to work with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstring>

#include"cuda_runtime.h"
#include"device_launch_parameters.h"


// size of different arrays
const uint32_t g_size = 55000U;
const uint32_t g_det_size = 40000U;
const uint32_t g_sum_size = 30000U;


// kernel: dynamical array inside device
__global__ void dmemd(cuDoubleComplex *d_sum) {
    int gid = blockIdx.x;

    // dynamical array
    cuDoubleComplex *d_det = new cuDoubleComplex[g_det_size];

    // compute det
    for (int i = 0; i < g_det_size; i++) {
        d_det[i] = make_cuDoubleComplex((i * 1.0 / (gid + 1)) * (0.01 / g_det_size),
                                        (i * 1.0 / (gid + 1)) * (0.01 / g_det_size) );
    }

    cuDoubleComplex dt_sum = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0, 0.0);
    // compute sum
    for (int i = 0; i < g_sum_size; i++) {
        dt_sum = cuCadd(dt_sum, d_det[i]);
    }

    // sum linked with each block id
    d_sum[gid] = dt_sum;

    delete[] d_det;
}

// kernel: dynamical device array from host
__global__ void dmemh(cuDoubleComplex *d_sum, cuDoubleComplex *d_det) {
    int gid = blockIdx.x;

    // compute det
    for (int i = 0; i < g_det_size; i++) {
        d_det[gid * g_det_size + i] = make_cuDoubleComplex((i * 1.0 / (gid + 1)) * (0.01 / g_det_size),
                                      (i * 1.0 / (gid + 1)) * (0.01 / g_det_size) );
    }

    cuDoubleComplex dt_sum = make_cuDoubleComplex(0.0, 0.0);
    // compute sum
    for (int i = 0; i < g_sum_size; i++) {
        dt_sum = cuCadd(dt_sum, d_det[gid * g_det_size + i]);
    }

    // sum linked with each block id
    d_sum[gid] = dt_sum;
}


int main() {

    double complex tsum;
    tsum = 0.0 + 0.0 * I;

    double complex *sum;
    sum = (double complex*)malloc((sizeof(double complex)) * g_size);

    cuDoubleComplex *d_sum;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_sum, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * g_size);
    cudaMemset(&d_sum, 0, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * g_size);


    dim3 block(1);
    dim3 grid(g_size);

    // kernel: dynamical array inside device
    //dmemd << < grid, block >> > (d_sum);

    // kernel: dynamical device array from host
    cuDoubleComplex *d_det;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_det, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * g_det_size * g_size);
    cudaMemset(&d_det, 0, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * g_det_size * g_size);

    dmemh << < grid, block >> > (d_sum, d_det);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();


    // memory copy host to device
    cudaMemcpy(sum, d_sum, sizeof(double complex) * g_size,
               cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    for (int i = 0; i < g_size; i++) {
        tsum += sum[i];
    }

    printf("Total sum: %.16E,%.16E \n", creal(tsum), cimag(tsum));

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you really need g_det_size * g_size * sizeof(complex) temp storage at once, there is nothing you can do if your GPU does not have enough memory.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor I now tried making blocks of 50k, that is, for 120k: 50k, 50k, 20k. So the memory, is broken down to g_det_size * 50k, g_det_size * 50k, g_det_size * 20k

Comment: It could help if you at least try to describe what happens between initialization and summation such that you need to use temporary memory. While I would think that allocating memory once on the host is much cheaper (best benchmark it for yourself), you can increase the "Malloc Heap Size", see [Heap Memory Allocation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#heap-memory-allocation).

Comment: For the block local reduction with multiple threads per block I would generally use [`cub::BlockReduce::Sum()`](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/classcub_1_1_block_reduce.html). But to use this you will need to know at compile time how many elements there are per thread. I.e. `elements_per_thread = (g_det_size + block_size - 1) / block_size`.

Comment: For parallelization, I would start with 1 thread block of 128 threads per j, and  compute a block wide reduction as explained by paleonix. the start for each j is given by the prefix sum of deg_len

Comment: Can you provide a fully working example for the serial implementation? What is the range of values in `deg_where_d` and `where` ?

Comment: @AbatorAbetor `deg_where_d` and `where` are computed using large data files, both range [0:d_det_size]

Comment: Okay, so you have `g_size=120000` chunks of data, each chunk has an independent set of `g_det_size = 50000` determinats. Computations of chunk `j` require only its own 50000 determinates. Only `deg_len[j]` determinates of are accessed by chunk `j`.  You want the total sum of all chunk resuts. Is that correct?

Comment: @AbatorAbetor Yes, that is correct. I think the efficient parallelization idea would be the same for the sample code as well

Answer (score 2):

For better parallelization, you can use multiple threads per threadblock and perform a parallel sum.

This requires computing a prefix sum of deg_len beforehand. The main kernel could look something like this. it assumes that d_det is computed for all thread blocks of the kernel:

```
#include <cub/cub.cuh>
#include <cuda/std/complex>


using ComplexT = cuda::std::complex<double>;

template<int threadblocksize>
__global__
void sumKernel(
    ComplexT* sumPerBlock,
    const ComplexT* all_d_det,
    int g_det_size,
    const int* deg_where_d,
    const int* where,
    const int* deg_len,
    const int* deg_len_prefixsum,
    int numJ
){
    using BlockReduce = cub::BlockReduce<ComplexT, threadblocksize>;
    __shared__ typename BlockReduce::TempStorage reduceTmp;

    int j = blockIdx.x;
    if(j < numJ){
        ComplexT* const d_det = all_d_det + size_t(g_det_size) * j;
        ComplexT x1 = d_det[deg_where_d[j]];

        int start = deg_len_prefixsum[j];
        int len = deg_len[j];

        ComplexT threadSum(0,0);
        for(int k = start + threadIdx.x; k < start + len; k += blockDim.x){
            threadSum += d_det[where[k]] * deg[k]
        }
        ComplexT blocksum = BlockReduce(reduceTmp).Sum(threadSum);
        //blocksum is only valid for thread 0
        if(threadIdx.x == 0){
            sumPerBlock[j] = blocksum * x1;
        }
    }
}
```

After the kernel, you can use `thrust::reduce` to sum up the per block results.

To limit the amount of used memory, limit the number of blocks and use multiple kernel calls.

```
constexpr int blocksize = 128;
int maxblocksByMemory = maxmemory / memory per block
int maxblocksByOccupancy = ... //use cuda occupancy api for kernel
int maxblocks = min(maxblocksByMemory, maxblocksByOccupancy)

ComplexT* d_sumPerJ; //sizeof(ComplexT) * g_size
ComplexT* d_det_for_maxblocks; //sizeof(ComplexT) *g_det_size * maxblocks

for(int j = 0; j < g_size; j += maxblocks){
   int numJ = min(g_size - j,maxblocks);
   //fill determinates for current loop iteration
   computeDeterminates(d_det_for_maxblocks)
   //compute correct prefix sum for current loop iteration
   thrust::exclusive_scan(...)
   sumKernel<blocksize><<<maxblocks, blocksize>>>(
       d_sumPerJ + j,
       d_det_for_maxblocks,
       // pass correct data pointers for current loop iteration
       numj
   );
}
ComplexT finalSum = thrust::reduce(thrust::device, d_sumPerJ, d_sumPerJ+g_size);
```

Comment: Both thrust and cub are included in recent cuda toolkits. They are also available on github so you can simply download them.

Comment: @AnomalousPhysicst cub, not cuBLAS

Comment: @AnomalousPhysicst Just download it.